# Using counters not yet defined

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering, counters, exam

At the moment I am writing a template used for homework. For style reasons, I would like to have a title page with a table containing all maximum points per exercise and free space, for the number of points I got.

I defined an own theorem-environment `exercise` that becomes the maximum amount of points possible in this `exercise`. e.g. an `exercise` with 4 points maximum

```
\begin{exercise}[4]
     Some text here...
\end{exercise}
```

I can use this number (stored as a counter) later in the document, but I would like to have the table as first page.

Is it possible to access a value before it is defined? Something like the table-of-contents would be ok. First compilation all values are stored, the table shows zeroes. Second compilation, the table shows the correct numbers.
In short words, I would like to see something like in the `exam` class, where you are able to define points and they are shown on titlepage. But since our exercises are quite more complex, I would like to use my own package and replicate this mechanic.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You don't mean 'counters' itself that aren't defined, you mean that counter values are used before they are assigned, rather

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This stores the credit points to a `.exer` file, which is like a `.toc`, begin displayed with `\listofcredits`, the total number of credit points is displayed at the end of the list.

The `\@starttoc` macro loads the `.exer` file.

More information is needed however, to improve design and features.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{totcount}
\newcounter{exercise}

\newtotcounter{totalcredits}



\newenvironment{exercise}[1][1]{%
  \refstepcounter{exercise}%
  \addtocontents{exer}{\protect\contentsline{section}{\protect\numberline{\theexercise}}{#1}}
  \addtocounter{totalcredits}{#1}%
}{}

\AtEndDocument{%
  \addtocontents{exer}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}\par\protect\hrule}
  \addtocontents{exer}{\protect\contentsline{section}{Total}{\number\totvalue{totalcredits}}}
}


\makeatletter
\newcommand{\listofcredits}{%
  \section*{Credit points}
  \@starttoc{exer}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listofcredits

\clearpage

\begin{exercise}[4]
  Foo
\end{exercise}


\begin{exercise}[17]
  Foobar
\end{exercise}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Since `exercise` is apparently defined without any title, there's not much left to write to the `.exer` file, giving more information on the `exercise` in `\listofcredits`